# Not generating coverage file in Android Test

Tags: java, android, testing, android-emulator, jenkins-plugins

I had SDK 18 and after update to SDK 20 I have problem with generate coverage files.

> .../coverage.ec: Permission denied ... [report]nothing to do: no
>   runtime coverage data found in any of the data files...

I used "ant clean emma  install test"
when I tried "ant all clean emma debug install test" I had:

> "all" does not exist...

Can anyone help?